# Any hints for https form get and post parse html project android?

Tags: https, webview, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm creating an Android app that should do the following;

1. Use a form on a https (SSL!) page to login and receive a cookie
2. Issue httpGET actions to get html
3. parse that html and show it in a view, list or something.

I've been fooling around with Jsoup, httpUnit and HTMLUnit for quite some time now, but I'm running in to several problems;

A. Login is fine, works.. (I get the website's welcome page) but then, when I issue a GET statement (and include the cookie), I am redirected to the login form. So the response html is not what I expected. (might have something to do with a keepalivestrategy?)

B. InputBuffers are too small to receive entire HTML pages and set them up for parsing.

NB : I do not have control over the webserver

I'm totally new at this, so a tutorial or code snippets would be helpful.

For instance, this is what I use to login to the website :

```
public int checkLogin() throws Exception {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", getUsername()));
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getPassword()));
    data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit_login", "Logmein"));

    Log.d(TAG, "Cookie name : " + getCookieName());
    Log.d(TAG, "Cookie cont : " + getCookie());

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(BASE_URL);
request.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
request.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",false);
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data, "UTF-8"));

    HttpResponse response;

    httpsclient.getCookieStore().clear();

    List<Cookie> cookies = httpsclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    Log.d(TAG, "Number of Cookies pre-login : "  + cookies.size());

    response = httpsclient.execute(request);

    cookies = httpsclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    Log.d(TAG, "Number of Cookies post-login : "  + cookies.size());
    String html = "";

    // Problem : buffer is too small!

    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Log.v(TAG, "Ik heb nu dit : " + doc.toString());

    if (cookies.size() > 0){
        storeCookie(cookies.get(0).getName(), cookies.get(0).getValue());
        return MensaMobileActivity.REQUEST_SUCCESS;
    } else {
        return MensaMobileActivity.REQUEST_ERROR;           
    }

}
```

Comment: Q: your web client is Android, it's talking to an external web server, correct?  You have control over the web server, correct?  Is it Apache or IIS?  Q: Where do Jsoup, httpUnit and HTMLUnit fit into "Android"?  Please clarify a bit.

Comment: No, trying to create an App that surfs a website and parses HTML to present it in a different form. Hope clarification is in the OP now, after my edit. thnx

Comment: OK - you're simply trying to code an HTTP client on Android, correct?  If you're not already using it, the Apache HTTP library is probably your best bet.  For example:  http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/  If you have any further questions, please post back any code with specific problems.

Comment: That looks good! Nice blogpost! Does it work with https (secure) connections? The process entity method, does that suffer from limitations (i.e. What is the maximum size of the HTML to be returned as message?)

Comment: I tried your sample project.. It doesn't work with https, I'll try to modify it, to support SSL.. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't handle the SSL certificate at all, that's at least a part of the problem. I struggled starting to learn this recently as well. This block of code will grab the SSL cert from the webpage you're accessing.

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(YOUR_WEBPAGE_HERE);
        HttpsURLConnection connect = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connect.connect();
        Certificate[] certs = connect.getServerCertificates();

        if (certs.length > 0) {

            cert = new File("YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_FILE");
            //write the certificate obtained to the cert file.
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(cert);
            os.write(certs[0].getEncoded());

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```